# How to take entirely android os as a image file?

Tags: android, backup

1-I have rooted my tablet(android 5.1.1).
2-I have installed some apps as System app...
3-I need to take a backup of my entire android os, including data_user and system apps, all together.
is it possible to take an image of android os including every things?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.  Try android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

At first, use `mount` or cat `/proc/mtd` command to identify your block devices. And then copy all image to file:

`cat /dev/mtd/mtd16ro > /sdcard/my_system_image.bin`

/dev/mtd/mtd16ro - system partition at my tablet (your may be different)

/sdcard/my_system_image.bin - your image at your sdcard